# How to translate idiom "red herring"?

Tags: idioms

From wikipedia: The idiom "[red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)" is used to refer to something that misleads or distracts from the relevant or important issue.

Is there literal translation or similar idiom?

Comment: Are you referring to this idiom meaning in financial world? Like here: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/redherring.asp? If yes, then I think there are no exact Russian equivalent.

Comment: I think, it's:<br />
уловка <= *adj.*<br />
сбить с толку <= *action*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there a phrase in Russian with the exact same meaning as *red herring*.  Depending on the context, you could use:

> Отвлечение внимания
>   Отвлекающий аргумент
>   Отвлекающий манёвр
>   Ложная улика
>   Ложный манёвр

There is term *копчёная сельдь*, however I've never actually heard it in speech.

Comment: "Отвлекающий маневр" it's most commonly used phrase in this context...

Comment: @Sergey As I mentioned, it really depends on the context.  _Отвлекающий маневр_ refers to something that was done/presented on purpose.  When it's more accidental, then _ложная улика_ would be a better option.  For example, you are trying to find out why your car doesn't start and you see a disconnected wire in the engine compartment.  You start thinking that it's the reason - and are trying to figure out where it's supposed to go and why it's disconnected - and so on.  Eventually, turns out that the car is not starting because it doesn't have petrol.  The disconnected wire is the red herring.

Comment: How about "(навести на) ложный след"? It seems somewhat related to the English idiom's alleged origins.

Comment: @AlexG Sorry but I think in russian society any thing related to crime/investigation like "улика" are very limited in context. Since I'm [bela]russian I will use "неверная предпосылка" rather then your "ложная улика"in this engine related example.

Comment: I agree with "ложный след" (false trail) being a very good option here.